# After applying a ransack date-field filter same output tickets are repeating instead of one

Tags: ruby, filter, rubygems, ransack, ruby-on-rails-7

Current result: In deadline filter, it is considering the first box as "from date " and the second as "to date"  and on applying the filter same tickets are repeating
Expected result: The deadline filter should work properly and on applying the filter tickets should not repeat
View:-

```
   <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label>Deadline Date</label>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <%= f.date_field :developers_deadline_date_gteq, class:"fa fa-calendar form-control", id: "todate-form" %>
              <%= image_tag("datepickerArrow.svg", alt: "image is not loaded", class:"date-img") %>
              <%= f.date_field :developers_deadline_date_lteq, class:"fa fa-calendar form-control", id: "fromdate-form" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Controller:-

```
@q = ClientRequest.with_resource_info_and_developer.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page]).ransack(params[:q])
@client_requests = @q.result
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it's got something to do with the way I'm passing params to Ransack but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What does `with_resource_info_and_developer` do? Does it add JOINs to the database query?

Comment: Yes, it is for include join in rails                                                                                    
scope :with_resource_info_and_developer, -> { includes(:resource_infos, :developers) }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database JOINs can lead to duplicate results, depending on the type of relation between both tables and the conditions run.

Just add [`distinct`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct) to your query to tell Ruby on Rails to only return unique records:

```
@q = ClientRequest
       .with_resource_info_and_developer
       .page(params[:page])
       .per(params[:per_page])
       .ransack(params[:q])
       .distinct
```